# Moving incoming messages to SIM card in Android

Tags: android, sms, sim-card

I need to move the incoming messages in my android phone directly to the sim card. I know I can click the message and move manually to SIM, but I need to do it automatically. I couldnt find that option anywhere in the settings. I am also fine with an app doing this.

Comment: as far as I know there is no option like that in Android. Is to move the message to your sim the only possibility? Otherwise you could use https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zegoggles.smssync what can save your messages to your google acc

Comment: Actually I am developing a program that listens for incoming messages in the phone from a PC and triggers an OS level action in the PC. The program is only able to read SMS from the SIMCard at present. Or if you can suggest a program that reads messages from the phone memory and can trigger an event in the PC, that would also work.

Comment: Okay now I got the problem.. I thought you were just searching a possibility to store your messages... I actually have no good suggestion for that - sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use AT commands (in your program). E.g. AT+CPMS="SM","SM","SM" - this makes your phone to use its SIM card as the SMS storage.